# Calling objective C method from c++ class method

Tags: c++, objective-c

Is it possible to call an objective C method from a C++ class method? I am aware this has been answered to an extent but none of the accepted answers appear to be working for me as I get 'use of undeclared identifier'  when trying to use the objective C instance variable (a pointer to self) to call the method.

```
@interface RTSPHandler : NSObject {   
    id thisObject;
}
```

implimentation:

```
-(int)startRTSP:(NSString *)url {

    thisObject = self;
    //  start rtsp code  
}

void DummySink::afterGettingFrame(unsigned frameSize, unsigned numTruncatedBytes,
                              struct timeval presentationTime, unsigned ) {

    [thisObject receivedRTSPFrame:fReceiveBuffer];

}    

-(void)receivedRTSPFrame:(NSMutableData* )data {

    // decode frame..

}
```

error: use of undeclared identifier 'thisObject'

Comment: does your c++ file have a .mm extension? you can only mix obj-c and c++ in an obj-c++ file

Comment: yes it does.. I forgot to mention this sorry!

Comment: What's the relationship between `RTSPHandler` and `DummySink`?

Comment: RTSPHandler contains reference to C++ libraries for rtsp handling. The dummySink class is subclassed from those libraries and called when a frame is received. From here I have my own decoder written in Objective C so it's just a case of calling that method with the data.

Comment: I am probably going about this the wrong way. Would I be correct in thinking this is a scoping issue.. A class in C++ can only have access to variables set in its creation not from an outside environment such as the objective C class implementation.

Comment: This is complicated to answer.  How much C++ is in the app?  Is the C++ just limited to calling a third-party library or something?

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare `thisObject` as a static variable like below

```
static id thisObject;
@implementation RTSPHandler
//...
@end
```

**UPDATE**

Ok. Now I see my answer is hilarious. Let's get through the task and make the solution more appropriate.

There will be two separate classes with separated interface and implementation parts. Say the objective-c class named `OCObjectiveClass` (Objective-c class) and `DummySink` (C++ class). Each `DummySink` instance must have an object of `OCObjectiveClass` as a c++ class member.

This is interface part of `OCObjectiveClass` (with a ".h"-extension):

```
@interface OCObjectiveClass : NSObject
  //...
  - (void)receivedRTSPFrame:(void *)frame; // I don't know what is the frame's type and left it with a simple pointer
  //...
@end
```

This is the interface part of `DummySink` (with a ".h"-extension too):

```
#import "OCObjectiveClass.h" // include objective-c class headers
class DummySink
{
  OCObjectiveClass *delegate; // reference to some instance
  //...
  void AfterGettingFrame(unsigned frameSize, unsigned numTruncatedBytes,struct timeval presentationTime, unsigned);
  //...
}
```

`AfterGettingFrame` function realization must be in `DummySink` class implementation part (not ".cpp" extension, it must be ".mm" to work with objective-c classes and methods).

```
void DummySink::afterGettingFrame(unsigned frameSize, unsigned numTruncatedBytes,
                              struct timeval presentationTime, unsigned ) {

    [delegate receivedRTSPFrame:fReceiveBuffer];

}
```

Don't forget to set the `delegate` value.

```
- (void)someMethod
{
  OCObjectiveClass *thisObject;
  // initialize this object
  DummySink sink;
  sink.delegate=thisObject;
  sink.DoWork();
}
```

Comment: So you can only have one instance of the class?  Is that a good thing?

Comment: This was the solution, although I am not sure why it works. Much appreciated :)

Comment: @Md1079 @trojanfoe is right. `thisObject` is the only instance for the whole class. Be careful.